# Как добавить тег script в массив JS

Tags: javascript, html, массивы

У меня появилась необходимость хранить html код в массиве js, с последующим выводом кода в iframe.Вcё работает, но как только в значении появляется тег **< script >< /script >** вылетает ошибка. Как от неё избавиться ?

**Мой код:**

```js
let code_data = [`<html>
     <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
      </head>
      <body>
          <h1>Текст</h1>
          <script></script>
      </body>
    </html>`, `body{
     background:#000;
        color:#fff;
    }`];
```

**Ошибка в инструментах разработчика Chrome**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let code_data = [`<html>
     <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
      </head>
      <body>
          <h1>Текст</h1>
          <script></` + `script>
      </body>
    </html>`, `body{
     background:#000;
        color:#fff;
    }`];
    
console.log(code_data);
```

Comment: Если даже этот код решает проблему, было бы неплохо объяснить, чем она вызвана, и почему так ее не будет